# Close the [vault] forever?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) has the following wiki:

> Vault is: A commercial, proprietary revision control system by SourceGear LLC which markets its product as a replacement for Microsoft's Visual Source Safe, a secret management tool by HashiCorp or a secrets service by Azure (Azure Key Vault).

Great. So the tag means three different things, depending on context? Sounds like an useless tag.

Proposal:

- Anything regarding HashiCorp Vault can be retagged as [hashicorp-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashicorp-vault)
- Anything regarding Azure Keyvault can be retagged as [azure-keyvault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-keyvault)
- Anything regarding Sourcegear Vault can be retagged as [sourcegear-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegear-vault)

The three proposed tags already exist, it's just a matter of removing the extraneous [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) tag when one of those three is already applied to a post, and determining which of the three is appropriate from context when [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) appears on its own.

**Update**
The total list of `*vault` tags is daunting:
[hashicorp-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashicorp-vault) 
[ansible-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-vault) 
[sourcegear-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegear-vault) 
[spring-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-vault) 
[data-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-vault) 
[azure-backup-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-backup-vault) 
[chef-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef-vault) 
[paypal-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-vault) 
[bukkit-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bukkit-vault) 
[autodesk-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autodesk-vault) 
[contentful-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contentful-vault)

Comment: Too many _secrets_ ([c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUt7D4PnjxU)). Sounds like a conspiracy theory

Comment: By my reading of the tag wiki, all legitimate [vault] tags should be retagged as [hashicorp-vault] (the two tags are synonyms of each other). Note that the product advertises itself as a replacement for the other products. Therefore, the other tags wouldn't be correct unless they were included as a second tag to indicate which product [hashicopr-vault] was being used to replace.

Comment: @Waylan Hashicorp Vault, Azure KeyVault, and SourceGear Vault are all completely different things. The former two are active, currently-maintained secret management tools (e.g. two independent tools that serve the same purpose but are **not** the same thing). The latter is a completely separate tool with a different purpose.

Comment: Unrelated, but (i.e.)

Comment: @Backgammon I always mix the two up. :(

Comment: This tag appears to have returned. It seems like it's a synonym for `[hashicorp-vault]` now, but the tag synopsis really only says what it *isn't*, not what it *is*. In any case, I don't have the requisite reputation to suggest a synonym, but there are around 200 `[vault]` questions.

Answer (score 13):

That's two pages of retag. I could do this one in a few hours alone. I'm 100% for it.

EDIT: Somebody started the cleanup already. It's down to 48 now.

Comment: There are a surprisingly large number of ambiguous usages of the tag. At least, they're ambiguous to me. Maybe not to others. That's why I posted the question!

Comment: We could retag to unambiguous ones first, and then look at what dregs are left over.  Anything so ambiguous that we don't know which product they are talking about should probably be closed and deleted.